# Chat SE site thinks I have got higher rep than I actually have

Tags: discussion, bug, reputation, chat

I know that on the [SE Chat site](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) on your user profile that it will round up your rep points to the nearest hundred. But I have just noticed that it is now rounding my rep up to 2.7k when I actually only have 2,483 on the site that it is meant to be getting my rep from. Here is a screenshot of what I mean by where it rounds it:

[image: Toroidal main chat site profile]

I have also noticed that in the chat (and I think that this is the reason for why it is rounding it up to 2.7k) it thinks that my rep is:

[image: Toroidal chat rep]

But on no site do I have this much rep, so why is it showing up as this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah, [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

If I remember correctly, the parent user is really, the first account you started with is Ask Ubuntu, hence it being your parent user. The 2.7k shown is not *just* the rep you have from Ask Ubuntu, which is about 2.5k as you mentioned. It also includes your *Meta Stack Exchange* account. Why?

Simply because that account is elgible in your flair due to the fact you have over 200 rep on this site. That 2.7k is the ***combined*** rep of Ask Ubuntu and Meta Stack Exchange. You can try it out by attaching flair for total rep count on your bio. Since only those two sites have 200+ rep, only those two rep contribute to the total rep count. That is what the 2.7k is representing.

I hope this helps you!